# html, select option, with jquery click only works in firefox

Tags: jquery, html

This is only working in Firefox and I can not find out why. Click on the orange span works in every browser. Click on the select option only works in Firefox... Why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.click').click(function() {
                alert("clicked");
            });
        });
    </script>

    <select>
        <option class="click" value="">click</option>
    </select>

    <br /><br /><br /><br />


    <span class="click" style="display:inline-block;width:50px;height:20px;background-color:orange;padding:4px;">click</span>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant click a select option, you can capture a the **change** event in select, this works on all browsers:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document.getElementById("colors")).change(function() {
            alert($(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>

<select id="colors">
    <option value="click1">click2text</option>
    <option value="click2">click2text</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `select#colors` is a bad selector as it ruins the regex and making it not using `document.getElementById` for no reason.

Comment: thanks for the answers. I liked this one before the document.getElement... edit. I changed the id="" to class. thanks

Comment: The `getElementById` is much more efficient by the way thats why i changed, but for non complex applications `select#colors` will do.

Comment: now `this` isn't the select... you totally broke the code now! and from the docs: `For id selectors, jQuery uses the JavaScript function document.getElementById(), which is extremely efficient. When another selector is attached to the id selector, such as h2#pageTitle, jQuery performs an additional check before identifying the element as a match.`

Comment: @gdoron could you please explain "it ruins the regex" and why is the code totally broken now?

Comment: @gdoron `this` is exactly the select, check you facts, so much efford to bash down my answer, enjoy.

Comment: Ohh, I'm terribly sorry, I didn't notice you used jQuery after the `document.getElementById`, my bad. +1!

Comment: it means, that jQuery checks the selector if it's `#somethig`, if you add it extra details, the regex testing the selector won't identify the selector as id selector, so another checks will  need to be make. it's  not a disaster but is avoidable.

Answer (score 1):

`onclick` isn't a standard event of `<option>`, it's nice that firefox added that, but it's not defined in the spec.

You should use the `<select>`'s onchange` event instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('select').change(function() {
            if (this.value == "theValue")
                alert("clicked");
        });
    });
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, your explanation onclick, option and firefox spec is awesome, I dindt know and I really appreciate (+1)  $('select') didnt work straight away

Comment: @caramba, well, it's a snippet... anyway the accepted answer has problems in it, I think you should wait until he fixes them.

Comment: ok, thanks, what about I changed the id like Eldar had it first to class, is that ok?

Comment: @caramba, it's fine and even better.

Comment: THANK YOU for all the answers!